# Getting this error in laravel unexpected '?' in /home/n/public_html/d/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233 )

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I am using cron to mail users after 1 min but it's giving me this error

```
 unexpected '?' in /home/nonnon/public_html/dispatchSystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

but my laravel is working fine its just giving me an error in cron.

```
   my laravel version '5.5.19'
   my server php version 7
```

can anybody help me? if I have to update the version from where I can update it for this particular file in cpanel. i don't want to upset my other sites on the server because of the php version updation.

Comment: _"my server php version 7"_ <- that seems unlikely at this stage, at least for the CLI / cron usage

Comment: dont know to i can solve this problem i have checked this php version with phpinfo file

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 5.5** requires **PHP7** to run. The error you're getting is caused by the **null coalescing operator** introduced in PHP7 and used in **helpers.php**

You can check that in the **Laravel 5.5 upgrade guide** here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0

You'll need to either upgrade PHP or downgrade Laravel framework.

Comment: but i have another server where my laravel version is 5.7.5 and my php version is 5.3.29 and its working file.                                                                                                                     and second then why my laravel working and i am getting this error in cron execution.

Comment: Perhaps the helpers.php file is not used and hence not loaded, so no parse error is triggered. Check the 5.5 upgrade guide here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The parse error was caused by Laravel.  Unfortunately `Laravel` version 5.5 depends on `PHP` version 7, so you can try to use Laravel version 5.1 which is matching your environment.

Comment: i have updated my vendor folder with 5.2.45'; and its giving me this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler() in /home/nonnon/public_html/dispatchSystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php on line 59